# ItemUpdating method for an item event reciever is called three times

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, library

I've created an asset library for holding pictures and I've created an event reciever for the ItemUpdating event. When the item is updated, the method is called three times. I've noticed that two of the times the properties.ListItem is null.

My library settings are: 
"Require content approval" to "Yes"
"No versioning"
"Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited" is "No"

I've searched the problem and found out that if the "require checkout" option of the library is set to yes, the event receiver should have a similar behaviour as it does some work checking in and out the document. However mine is not.

If anyone have any insight in this, please share :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you update the same item in your code, you should use `EventFiringEnabled` property, take a look at this [post](http://sharepointdevelopertopics.blogspot.com/2011/04/changes-disabling-event-firing-in.html)

Comment: That's really helpful post, thanks. However I was looking for somrthing else. I do want the event to fire as I have some custom logic in them too. What I want to know is why the ItemUpdating event is firing 3 times and what kind of work is done in the 2 calls when the properties.ListItem parameter is null. It's interesting to me as there should not be any checkin/checkout in the list. Or does checkin/checkout always happen for item and it's just hidden from the user?